# css animation when the page is open

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

i need to develop a css animation, like that in the code below but it should be running only one time, not infinite times, when the html page is opening, how can set this animation from infite times to one time?

This is the code,

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Open Cube</title>
        <h1>Apertura Cubo</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sk-folding-cube">
            <div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
            <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sk-folding-cube {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
          transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}

.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1); 
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
          animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
          transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
          animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s; 
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
          animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  } 25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1; 
  } 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  } 
}

@keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  } 25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1; 
  } 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0; 
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
-webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s infinite linear both;
```

To this:

```
-webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s 1 linear both;
animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s 1 linear both;
```

Comment: thank's it works, but i used this animation for a cube opening and after the opening of the cube the faces should remain in the view and in this way the faces disappear

Comment: That's why it would have been set to `infinite`, if you don't want the faces to reappear then there has to be another way of writing the animation

Answer (score 0):

To keep animation ending and remain in the final tate, you need to use also  [`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> **`forwards`**
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

```
-webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s linear forwards both;
        animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s linear forwards both;
```

```css
.sk-folding-cube {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s linear forwards both;
  animation: sk-foldCubeAngle 2.4s linear forwards both;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(90deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(180deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotateZ(270deg);
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.sk-folding-cube .sk-cube4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sk-foldCubeAngle {
  0%, 10% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(-180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%,
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(140px) rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-folding-cube">
  <div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use animate.css

The link:
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: This is for adding general animation, not for how to animate a page one time. This also doesn't explain how this would help.